# Take only one entry from SQL based on two columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query as below

```
select B.BidderId, I.TrackingNumber, B.Amount
from dbo.Items I
inner join dbo.Bids B on I.SaleId = B.SaleId
where I.item = '123' and I.IsRecycled = 0
```

Basically it will fetch all Bidders of Item 123,

Example result

```
BidderID 1 => trackingnumber 1 => amount =>1000
BidderID 1 => trackingnumber 1 => amount =>9200
BidderID 1 => trackingnumber 1 => amount =>8000
BidderID 2 => trackingnumber 1 => amount =>8200
BidderID 1 => trackingnumber 2 => amount =>50
```

As you can see there are multiple Bid amount for user with bidderid 1. How can I take only the row with maximum amount value of bidder1.

Result should be like this (consider only maximum amount for a user for an item).

```
BidderID 1 => trackingnumber 1 => amount =>1000
BidderID 2 => trackingnumber 1 => amount =>8200
BidderID 1 => trackingnumber 2 => amount =>50 (this is a diffrent item so included)
```

Comment: Did I miss something? <BidderID1, trackingnumber1> has values of 1000, 9200, and 8000. You said "only maximum amount" and yet your desired result includes the lowest value of the three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a simple aggregation:

```
select B.BidderId, I.TrackingNumber, MAX(B.Amount)
from dbo.Items I
inner join dbo.Bids B on I.SaleId = B.SaleId
where I.item = '123' and I.IsRecycled = 0
GROUP BY  B.BidderId, I.TrackingNumber
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `row_number()`

```
select *
from (
    select B.BidderId, I.TrackingNumber, B.Amount
        , row_number() over (partition by B.BidderId, I.TrackingNumber order by B.Amount desc) as rn
    from dbo.Items I
    inner join dbo.Bids B On I.SaleId = B.SaleId
    where I.item = '123' and I.IsRecycled = 0
) A where rn = 1
```